# Printable pairs?

Tags: java, android

Is there a way to create printable pairs? `pair.toString()` looks like this: `android.util.Pair@fd55fdb8` , it is very hard to debug when I need to print a lot of arrays which contain those pairs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't try this but it should work anyway:

Javadoc [Pair](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Pair.html)

```
public class PrintablePair extends Pair {
 public String toString() {
     return "" + first +"," + ,second //(they are public)
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just override `toString` method and that is: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Object.html

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean in Eclipse? If so, right click on an instance of a `Pair`, select `New Detail Formatter...` and enter something like:

```
String text = "{ " + first + ", " + second + " }";
text.toString();
```

And you should see the pair in the watch window.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, you can use `org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Pair` instead of `android.util.Pair`

Build pairs using `Pair.of(first, second)`

And the reason I am suggesting that is that this class contains a customization toString method alongside with a default toString which serves your needs:

```
Pair.of(1, 2).toString(); // prints (1,2)
Pair.of(1, 2).toString("%s_%s"); // prints 1_2
```

[Pair doc](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.9/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/Pair.html)